# C++ members using template in non-template class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

A clean rebuild in Visual Studio made the whole thing work.

--

In a Visual Studio MFC project, I am making a class to manage buttons.

Here is my problem : I need to add Click Handler at runtime so I can't use Message Map. So I had a clickHandler function pointer in my class, en a function to register the click handler. That was ok for global function, but I want to use class members as ClickHandlers.

After a lot search, I came to this function :

```
class NRButton : public CButton
{
    ...
    template<class Type>
    inline void SetClickHandler(
        void (*cb)(CObject * , void (CObject::*)()),
        Type * pt,
        void (Type::*fn)()
    )
    {
        callbackHandler = cb;
        objectHandler   = pt;
        clickHandler    = fn;
    }
    ...
 }
```

This function is implemented inline as you can see, but when I build my project I've got this linker error :

```
 FenetreParametrage.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __thiscall NRButton::SetClickHandler<class FenetreParametrage>(void (__cdecl*)(class CObject *,void (__thiscall CObject::*)(void)),class FenetreParametrage *,void (__thiscall FenetreParametrage::*)(void))" (??$SetClickHandler@VFenetreParametrage@@@NRButton@@QAEXP6AXPAVCObject@@P81@AEXXZ@ZPAVFenetreParametrage@@P82@AEXXZ@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: virtual int __thiscall FenetreParametrage::OnInitDialog(void)" (?OnInitDialog@FenetreParametrage@@UAEHXZ)
```

After cleaning the error message I've got that :

```
 FenetreParametrage.obj : error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "
   public: void __thiscall NRButton::SetClickHandler<class FenetreParametrage>(
     void (__cdecl*)(class CObject *,void (__thiscall CObject::*)(void)),
     class FenetreParametrage *,
     void (__thiscall FenetreParametrage::*)(void)
   )
 "
 référencé dans la fonction "
   public: virtual int __thiscall FenetreParametrage::OnInitDialog(void)
 "
```

I understand this error message, but I don't understand why it appears, my function declared inline, so why VS Compiler can't find its implementation ?

Thanks for your help

---

EDIT :

Here is the call to the function :

```
bouton->SetClickHandler(
    &FenetreParametrage::Callback,
    this,
    &FenetreParametrage::OnBoutonClick
);
```

Comment: might also help to post the entire OnInitFunction

Comment: Just added the full OnInitDialog. I started a clean rebuild.

Comment: Your code don't reproduce the error

Comment: Resolved : a clean rebuild made the whole thing work. F*cking Visual Studio.

Comment: @AMDG Please don't swear, but I know that sometimes it happens..